# how to clear cache of laravel app in centos server that uses nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, centos

enter image description herei'm using **centos** to host my laravel application,
when i upload the project first time using git, it will be cached, and when i change any file, changes doesn't apply, i tried all artisan commands that clear cache in laravel but didn't fix
the only way is to change the root directory of the application after each single change, is centos caching or nginx or laravel or other software in the server or the browser? even i cleared every thing in public/index.php and put `echo 'foo';` and still got old cached data

[screenshot of my nginx config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgZVa.png)
[screenshot of my nginx config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo18h.png)

Comment: Sounds like a very specific problem which has nothing to do with laravel.... when you hit php artisan cache:clear and php artisan view:clear it needs to clear them... if it doesn't then something is wrong with your implementation and maybe paths

Comment: i added screenshot of my nginx config file i'm not good with nginx i'm afraid that i did something wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried `systemctl restart php-fpm` now every thing worked as expected and all changes applied thank you a lot i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly directory permission issue you need to grant storage and bootstrap directory 777 permission level.  You need to run the following command on the root folder of your app

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

and

```
chmod -R 777 bootstrap
```

Then try to effect your changes.

Comment: i have already did that for storage now i did that for bootstrap to and then php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear  but still has no effect